# MFMessageComposeViewController - Getting stuck after sending SMS in ios7

Tags: ios7, sms

After sending SMS from my phone(it's working properly) in my project using the **MFMessageComposeViewController** I can't get back to the app or press cancel. Instead **I'm stuck in Apple SMS interface** and I can't do anything else then to restart the app. Do I miss something in didFinishWithResult or could it be something else? Thanks

```
 - (IBAction)sendSMS:(id)sender {
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller =
    [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];


   if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
  {
      NSString *str= @"Hi";
      controller.body = str;
       controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             @"", nil];
       controller.delegate = self;


      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                               completion:nil];

       [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

 }


- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult) result
{
    switch (result) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            break;

        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
        {
            UIAlertView *warningAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to send SMS!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [warningAlert show];
            break;
        }

        case MessageComposeResultSent:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Is the delegate method called?

Comment: Do you mean? MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate? In that case yes. I have it in the header file.

Comment: No, I'm saying if `messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult` is called. Does your app goes through this code?

Comment: Thanks a lot man! No only the code I show in the post maybe that could be it? Where would you put that code

Comment: Does your code goes through each line it should be (the `switch` for example, as I already asked)? Is `sendSMS` twice?

Comment: I dont know. :( That is the only code I have for the sms that you can see above

Comment: I mean, does your app goes through each line it should be? You can write 10k of lines, and never use them. Use BreakPoint or `NSLog` to know.